Where are IBM's DB2 and Oracle's SQLJ Translators?
I've been working on a Java project a year ago, and have used the Codehaus Mojo SQLJ Plugin for translating .sqlj files into accessible Java classes. As I have the old repository saved, I saw that the following <plugin> was inserted in my pom.xml:
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sqlj</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sqljDirs>
                            <sqljDir>src/main/sqlj/</sqljDir>
                        </sqljDirs>
                        <generatedSourcesDirectory>../sales-persistance/src/main/java</generatedSourcesDirectory>
                            <generatedResourcesDirectory>../sales-persistance/src/main/resources/ro/ibm/sqlj</generatedResourcesDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sqlj4</artifactId>
                    <version>4.29.29</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

It uses the com.ibm.db2:sqlj4 dependency for sqlj translation. From my research, SQLJ can be translated using one of the two translators: IBM's or Oracle's. Based on their documentation, such translators are only provided with their Databases (for example, Oracle with their Database 23c, and so on), and not as independent packages.
One year ago, this com.ibm.db2:sqlj4 translator was available on MavenCentral. At this moment, it isn't available anymore. From old projects found on GitHub, Oracle also had an SQLJ translator available without that Database Client (com.oracle:sqlj), but I can't seem to find it on any Maven repository anymore.
Any reason to why I cannot find independent versions of the translators anymore? Also, is there any possibility to download the jar files and simply add them locally through the pom.xml? Oracle and IBM do not provide any download links for those translators.

As of Oracle 12.2, server-side SQLJ is desupported.

SQLJ Support Inside Oracle Database
Starting with Oracle Database 12c release 2 (12.2), Oracle does not support running server-side SQLJ code.
Oracle supports using client-side SQLJ. However, Oracle does not support the use of server-side SQLJ, including running stored procedures, functions, and triggers in the database environment.

The Oracle 19 SQLJ Getting Started documentation states:

2.1.2 Requirements for Using the Oracle SQLJ Implementation
The following are required to use the Oracle SQLJ implementation:

A database system that is accessible using your JDBC driver

Class files for the SQLJ translator
Translator-related classes are available in the following file:
ORACLE_HOME/sqlj/lib/translator.jar


Note: For more information about translator.jar, refer to "Set the Path and Classpath".


Class files for the SQLJ run time.
ORACLE_HOME/sqlj/lib/runtime12.jar


Note: runtime12ee.jar has been deprecated since Oracle Database 11g Release 1. Use runtime12.jar instead.




Therefore, you should be able to get the appropriate JAR files from the database installation.

In this case, what's the difference between "client-side" and "server-side" SQLJ? Server-side explicitly refers to the JAR dependency available for use? As you said, only the SQLJ Translator available with a DB client is available for use. Is this the "client-side" they're referring to?

@MarioMateaș You can run Java inside the Oracle database and use it to write database functions and procedures and that, from an Oracle database point-of-view, is server-side. Prior to Oracle 12.2, you could use SQLJ in those Java functions; Oracle 12.2 and later you need to use JDBC for those server-side Java functions and procedures. Client-side is not running inside the database. You can also read the Introduction to SQLJ documentation.

I didn't state that "only the SQLJ Translator available with a DB client is available for use"; I quoted the documentation that tells you Oracle's documented place to find the JAR files - there may be other places, just not listed in the documentation.

I understand that sending queries from a Java application to an external database through SQLJ is client -side. I also understand that only server-side SQLJ is considered as deprecated. Also, I tried installing the latest Oracle Linux on a virtual machine, and neither the translator, nor the sqlj script (specified in the documentation so often) weren't found at ORACLE_HOME

@MarioMateaș It should be the Oracle database installation (not Oracle Linux).

Did you check the DB 23ai SQLJ developers guide?
Btyw, a deprecation notice has just been issued.
